# Calculate the Cumulative density.

Tags: probability-distributions

> $U$ is a random variable in the range of $(0,3)$. The random variable $W$ is the output of the clipper described by
>
> $W=g(U)=U$ for $U\le 1$ and $1$ for $U>1$
>
> find the cdf of $FW(w)$

Any ideas on how to solve this?

My idea was to graph it $g(U)$ vs $U$ and then see that the integral of the CDF is just area under the curve. However I think I am doing something wrong with my plot as I am getting the CDF$>1$?

Comment: "Cumulative density" is an oxymoron.  The word "cumulative" contradicts the word "density".  Probably you mean "cumulative distribution function".  That's what "cdf" stands for.

Comment: I don't get $FW(w)$, is it?

Comment: Is the distribution of *U* uniform (I would assume that from the symbol chosen, but it should be stated explicitly, if so)?

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is a uniformly distributed random variable, then its density function equals $1/3$ on the given interval. Also, $W$ has a range from zero to 1 (even though its domain is the range of $U$. For all values of $w$ between 0 and 1, the probability density is $1/3$, and for 1, it's $2/3$.

So,

$$
F_W(w) = \begin{cases} 
              0, & w \le 0, \\
              w/3, & 0 \lt w < 1, \\
              1, & w \ge 1
         \end{cases}
$$

Note the discontinuity.